# nextjs-auth0 trigger an error redirect on production

Tags: next.js, auth0

I have a problem with next-auth0 that I can't figure out where it's coming from.

In development everything works fine, but in production I get the following:

I have a menu with many buttons, one of them has a link to `/dashboard`. If I click on the button, instead of going to `/dashboard` the app redirects me to `/api/auth/login?returnTo=%2Fdashboard`, and shows me the 500 error page.

If I refresh the browser, I can access the login page.

If I type `/dashboard` by hand in the navigation bar, I can also access the login page.

But I can't get there through a link/button.

I would not know where this problem could be, I already reviewed and commented on all the redirects of `next.config.js` and nothing changed.

This is the code of /api/auth/[...auth0].js

```
// Node Modules
import {
  handleAuth, handleLogin, handleLogout
} from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

export default handleAuth({
  async login(req, res) {
    try {
      await handleLogin(req, res, {
        returnTo: "/dashboard",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("login error: ", error);
      res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
    }
  },

  async logout(req, res) {
    try {
      await handleLogout(req, res, {
        returnTo: "/",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("logout error: ", error);
      res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
    }
  },
});
```